# What age do kids really "master" the conversational basics?

Tags: speech

I'm not talking about when they speak their first words, or even their first sentences, but the age where they can carry on a decent conversation with (say) kids of the same age. What age does this happen?

Comment: What do you mean by conversation ? When do you estimate it to be decent ?  I've seen very young kids interact and "speak" together although their speech was impossible to understand from an adult perspective. When it becomes understandable, it is usually far from interesting from the same adult perspective. There are also no strict rules, was it for speech or anything else, so that would be more in some rather large timespan than a specific age...

Comment: Define *decent conversation*... I know some adults with whom I can't have what I would call a *decent conversation*...

Comment: You may need to refine this question. Does the conversation need to be disconnected from play (e.g. the _only_ topic is essentially abstract, unrelated to the toys in front of them)? How long a conversation are we talking about, a couple sentences or many minutes?

Comment: Also - you have two very different things here.  Being able to hold a conversation with an adult != being able to do so with a child - largely because the second requires *social* skills which typically develop after that of speech.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's a gradual process.

> **What are the milestones for speech and language development?**
>
> The first signs of communication occur when an infant learns that a cry will bring food, comfort, and companionship. Newborns also begin to recognize important sounds in their environment, such as the voice of their mother or primary caretaker. As they grow, babies begin to sort out the speech sounds that compose the words of their language. By 6 months of age, most babies recognize the basic sounds of their native language.
>
> Children vary in their development of speech and language skills. However, they follow a natural progression or timetable for mastering the skills of language. ...

Here's some of the milestones which relate directly to speaking:

> **1 to 2 Years**
> Uses some one- or two-word questions (“Where kitty?” or “Go bye-bye?”)
> Puts two words together (“More cookie”)
> Uses many different consonant sounds at the beginning of words
>
> **2 to 3 Years**
> Has a word for almost everything
> Uses two- or three-word phrases to talk about and ask for things
> Uses k, g, f, t, d, and n sounds
> Speaks in a way that is understood by family members and friends
> Names objects to ask for them or to direct attention to them
>
> **3 to 4 Years**
> Talks about activities at daycare, preschool, or friends’ homes
> Uses sentences with four or more words
> Speaks easily without having to repeat syllables or words
>
> **4 to 5 Years**
> Uses sentences that give many details
> Tells stories that stay on topic
> Communicates easily with other children and adults
> Says most sounds correctly except for a few (l, s, r, v, z, ch, sh, and th)
> Uses rhyming words
> Names some letters and numbers
> Uses adult grammar

Selected items from [Speech and Language Developmental Milestones](http://www.nidcd.nih.gov/health/voice/pages/speechandlanguage.aspx), NICD (USA), Updated September 2010, based upon *How Does Your Child Hear and Talk?*, courtesy of the American Speech–Language–Hearing Association.

So essentially the answer to your question - when can they carry on a decent-ish conversation - is "somewhere between age 3 and age 5".